# Laravel - How to Update two values

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to update two values in my data I want to update the first value as an int and the other one is string.

**TABLE STRUCTURE**

[image]

here is my input, the value `aircraft_id` is the first one to update and the other one is the `aircraft_refistration_number`

```
 <select name="aircraft_id" class="form-control" id="">
    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true"> Select </option>
       @foreach ($aircrafts as $aircraft)

    <option value="{{ $aircraft->aircraft_id }}">{{ $aircraft->aircraft_registration_number }}</option>

       @endforeach
  </select>
```

here is my table

[image]

here is where i update the `registered_company_name` which has to be string but then the output is the `aircraft_id`

```
$txtDescript = $request->input('aircraft_id');

  $aircraft = DB::table('settings')
  ->where('id', 4)
  ->update(['description' => $txtDescript]);
```

here is the `aircraft_id` which should be int or id's

```
  $airid = $request->input('aircraft_id');

    $aircraft = DB::table('series')
    ->update(['aircraft_id' => $airid]);
```

this one perfectly works

here is my output of the *problem*

[image]

**WHEREAS** it should be like THIS output which should be **correct**

[image]

Comment: Update as far as I know returns the count of rows affected. This could be the reason you have 1. Do you think this way too?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin no sir the 1 is the `aircraft_id` the correct update value should be `Incorporated Airlines` look above the value of my table field values

Comment: why this line? `$txtDescript = $request->input('aircraft_id');`

Comment: @SummerWinter Apologies, I didn't read properly. Okay, on this line `$txtDescript = $request->input('aircraft_id');` the input is actually aircraft_id. Isn't this what you expected?

Comment: There's possibility that what you needed should have been `registred_company_name` and not, `aircraft_id`

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin yes sir the input is actually the id or integer so i want to know how can i get the string value

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin problem is `registred_company_name` is not a string it does not return any value it is null

Comment: Then you could, `aircraft = DB::table('settings')
  ->where('aircraft_id', $request->input('aircraft_id')....` instead but then where will you get the value to update with?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin update is not working noting is being returned

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin here sir let me explain more

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin i cannot do this right `<option value="{{ $aircraft->aircraft_id }} || {{ $aircraft->aircraft_registration_number }}"></option>` ? so how can i get the aircraft_registration_number

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin becuase the only data i am getting is the `aircraft_id` so how can I also get the `aircraft_registration_number` ?

Comment: I think you should provide the explanations on your questions...

Comment: @SummerWinter can you show the table structures? Technically ID is stored and while retrieving, you perform an inner join to get the text.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin hello sir, I mean can I transform the `aircraft_id=1` into its coupled row value `aircraft_registration_number` ? like if aircraft id = 1 make it Incorporated Airlines

Comment: @vivek_23 yes sir done, please see the code above my question i edited it

Comment: @SummerWinter What is `aircraft_id`? Is it foreign key of some other table? In that case, you have to make it a foreign key. Currently, it's just a column.

Comment: ye sir you are right im also updating 1 table which also has `aircraft_id`

Comment: that is why im updating two tables and the other table must update as an int which is the `aircraft_id` and this table must update as string which is the `aircraft_registration_company`

Comment: @SummerWinter Then you need to have foreign key constraint in place first. Also, when the form gets posted, you will always have option `value` as the value inside `$request->input('aircraft_id')` and not the innerHTML of `<option>` tag. Also, there is no need to have a column for `aircraft_registration_company`. You only store the foreign key which is `aircraft_id` and while retrieving, you do an inner join between these 2 tables and get the text(company_name).

Comment: @SummerWinter Better share all relevant tables such as the one which has `aircraft_id` or maybe `id` as it's primary key.

Comment: @vivek_23 can you show me a code sir? im confused sorry :(

Comment: @SummerWinter What kind of code? I suggest you to learn [foreign keys](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) first.

Comment: @vivek_23 just please give me the sample of the inner join tables which has to update my current table and the other table please sir then ill just learn it from there thank you so much

Comment: @SummerWinter show me the `aircraft` table. Also, what is the name of the table you have shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take this longer form,

```
 <select name="aircraft_id" class="form-control" id="">
    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true" id="airselect"> Select </option>
       @foreach ($aircrafts as $aircraft)

    <option value="{{ $aircraft->aircraft_id }}">{{ $aircraft->aircraft_registration_number }}</option>
       @endforeach
  </select>
<input type="hidden" name="aircraft_name" id="aircraft_name" value="">
```

and set the value of the hidden field using jquery like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('change','.airselect',function(){
$selected=$( "#airselect option:selected" ).text();
$('#aircraft_name').val($selected);
});
});
```

and then adjust your controller like so

```
$txtDescript = $request->input('aircraft_name');
$aircraft = DB::table('settings')
  ->where('id', 4)
  ->update(['
description' => $txtDescript]);
```

and

```
$airid = $request->input('aircraft_id');

$aircraft = DB::table('series')
->update(['aircraft_id' => $airid]);
```

try it and let me here from you, i did not test the code

Comment: hello thank you for your answer, are you sure that the input type hidden is inside the `select` input?

Comment: hello it didnt work but you are correct i need a jquery or ajax to get the other value

Comment: Sorry for the input comment placed inside the select, it is an error on my part, it should be outside the <select> tag